# What is a NKJV like German version of the Bible?

Tags: bible

So I’m looking for a Bible in German that is like the NKJV in accuracy.

I specifically was looking at the verse

[‭‭Revelation‬ ‭21‬:‭8‬ ‭NKJV‬‬](https://bible.com/bible/114/rev.21.8.NKJV)

> But the cowardly, unbelieving, abominable, murderers, sexually immoral, sorcerers, idolaters, and all liars shall have their part in the lake which burns with fire and brimstone, which is the second death.

But the German translations I’ve seen recommended seem to be not as accurate like for sexual immoral they put, whores or Huren, or indecent (Unzüchtigen).

‭‭[Offenbarung‬ ‭21‬:‭8‬ ‭DELUT‬‬](https://bible.com/bible/51/rev.21.8.DELUT)

> Der Verzagten aber und Ungläubigen und Greulichen und Totschläger und Hurer und Zauberer und Abgöttischen und aller Lügner, deren Teil wird sein in dem Pfuhl, der mit Feuer und Schwefel brennt; das ist der andere Tod.

‭‭[Offenbarung‬ ‭21‬:‭8‬ ‭SCH2000‬‬](https://bible.com/bible/157/rev.21.8.SCH2000)

> Die Feiglinge aber und die Ungläubigen und mit Gräueln Befleckten und Mörder und Unzüchtigen und Zauberer und Götzendiener und alle Lügner — ihr Teil wird in dem See sein, der von Feuer und Schwefel brennt; das ist der zweite Tod.

Does anyone know a German Bible version that translates these things well? I only know a little German so to understand which words are which I’m using Google Translate.

I want to send some German verses but from & a good translation. I saw the Hoffnung für alle “Hope for all” translation does say sexually immoral in German but people said that it was a translation that isn’t as clear doctrinally.

Can someone help me?

Comment: Welcome to Christianity Stack Exchange.  Your question is somewhat confusing because it initially asks for a German Bible that is like the New King James Version, then you highlight a specific verse in Revelation‬ ‭21‬:‭8‬ ‭NKJV with regard to the expression "sexually immoral".  While I look into this, please take our Tour which explains how we are different to other sites: Revelation‬ ‭21‬:‭8‬ ‭NKJV

Comment: Check out this question and the answer given at the very end (which mentions a specific Bible in German): https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/27313/german-bible-translation-like-nkjv-esv-nasb-etc?rq=1